# returning maths values in a new command

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath

So I'm trying to construct a command which calls another command to make typing easier, but for some reason I'm not able to get the commands to return things properly. Here is what I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\mfunction}[4] {
    \def \lnum{#4}

    \ifnum\lnum=0
        {M_{{#1}_{{#2},{#3}}}}
    \else
        {M_{{#1}_{{#2},{#3}}^{k}}}
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\man}[3][0] {\mfunction{A}{#2}{#3}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mbn}[3][0] {\mfunction{B}{#2}{#3}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mdn}[3][0] {\mfunction{D}{#2}{#3}{#1}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \man[1]{n}{l} \coloneqq \{a\}\\
        \mbn{n}{k} \coloneqq \{b\} \\
        \mdn{n-1}{k} \coloneqq \{d\}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This is coming back with the errors that I'm missing '$' and '}' signs where I have '\end{align*}'. Oddly when I place the code directly into my 'quick' command I get the proper output. So the code that works is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\newcommand{\man}[3][0] {{M_{{A}_{{#2},{#3}}^{#1}}}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \man[1]{n}{l} \coloneqq \{a\}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Why would the first version not work and the second one work? Is something happening with my definition/if statement that is causing the new command to return data that is not intended?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the `calculator` package is of use to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the blank line after `\def \lnum{#4}`.

Comment: #facepalm That did the trick. Does the new line get returned in the command function as well then? I assumed it wouldn't be.

Comment: @AramPapazian TeX (usually) turns a blank line into a `\par` token: that's not allowed inside an `align`, so you get an error. Remember that a command simply inserts the material you've defined it with into where you use it: if you try writing your example with a blank line directly in the `align` you'll see the same error.

Comment: I just didn't realise TeX was converting the blank line into a \par token. I made the (bad) assumption that in \newcommand all blank lines would be 'filtered' out, but it also makes sense that it wouldn't. Is there a way to alter it so it isn't converted if I do want blank lines to make it more human readable?

Comment: You can add a line with just a `%`, then it will _almost_ look empty. Note that TeX also ignores the newline after a comment.

Answer (score 4):

A blank line is converted to `\par`, which is illegal in `align` and all math display environment.

There are also some other glitches in your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\mfunction}[4]{%
  \ifnum#4=0\relax
    M_{#1_{#2,#3}}%
  \else
    M_{#1_{#2,#3}^{k}}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\man}[3][0] {\mfunction{A}{#2}{#3}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mbn}[3][0] {\mfunction{B}{#2}{#3}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mdn}[3][0] {\mfunction{D}{#2}{#3}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \man[1]{n}{l} \coloneqq \{a\}\\
        \mbn{n}{k} \coloneqq \{b\} \\
        \mdn{n-1}{k} \coloneqq \{d\}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

There is no need of defining `\lnum`, as you can use `#4` directly in `\ifnum`. I also added `%` to protect the end-of-lines which would produce a space. It isn't strictly necessary here because the macro will be used in math mode, where spaces are ignored, but it's a good habit because for macros to be used in text mode spaces *are* significant.

You can choose between

```
\ifnum#4=0\relax
```

and

```
\ifnum#4=0
```

(with no `%`); `\relax` more clearly marks the end of the number, but in other circumstances, when full expandability is needed, it shouldn't be used (not the case here).

I also removed unnecessary braces.

Comment: Your solution is super elegant! This turned out to be the one I ended up using as it gave the most description. I had already accepted the other response so didn't want to take the reps away from Ian, but wanted to mention that this was a great explanation for future users. Thanks =)